# How to Display Python Flask DB entires in Jinja 2 html table

Tags: python, html, flask

I currently have a DB whose table I want to review inside of my web app via a specific route.

I want to view the Jinga2 output of the entires in the DB in a easy to read table via the app.

What I currently have works but it shows all the entries in one line instead of a table format like an excel spreadsheet.

My code is below:

```
 {% for row in rows %}  <tr>
  <td>{{ row.id }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ row.question }}</td>
  <td bgcolor="{{ row.stat_colour }}">{{ row.unit_status }}</td>  </tr>  >     
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having similar issues, I was able to get it to work by using the code block below for my html:

```
 <html !DOCTYPE>
 <head>
 <title>SQLite 3 DB Questions Table</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
 {% for row in rows %}
 <tr>
     <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ row.question }}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the opening tr before the start of the loop

```
<tr> {% for row in rows %}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it still wants to display everything horizontally instead of vertically